# IIS Redirect Rule from page a to b

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a redirect as follows :

```
     <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="http://mysite/ru/folder/pagename">
        <match url="http://d000097.tech.com/ru/Solutions/Visual+call+solutions/Products" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://d000097.tech.com/us/Solutions/Visual+call+solutions/Products" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

but it doesn't seem to be kicking in, can anyone see anything obvious wrong with above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the host portion in the urls.  IIS just matches the url after the host.  Change the rule to the following:

```
 <rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="http://mysite/ru/folder/pagename">
    <match url="^ru/Solutions/Visual+call+solutions/Products$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="us/Solutions/Visual+call+solutions/Products" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```